Concerning $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ and $\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3-t]$
Let $A=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3]$ and $B=\mathbb{C}[t^2,t^3-t]$.
We have $$A \cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle y^2-x^3 \rangle}$$
and $$B \cong \frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}{\langle y^2-x^3+2x^2-x \rangle}.$$
Indeed, $(t^3)^2-(t^2)^3=0$ and
$(t^3-t)^2-(t^2)^3+2(t^2)^2-(t^2)=t^6-2t^4+t^2-t^6+2t^4-t^2=0$.
I really apologize for the probably trivial question, but I am not sure if $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras or not.

Question: Are $A$ and $B$ isomorphic as $\mathbb{C}$-algebras?

It is clear that $A$ does not contain polynomials with $ct$, $c \in \mathbb{C}^*$,
but should this fact be relevant to my question?
Maybe this question may help.
Thank you for any comment.

Could it be that $B=\mathbb{C}[t]$? Therefore, $A$ and $B$ are non-isomorphic.

No, these are not isomorphic, nor are either isomorphic to $\Bbb C[t]$. $A$ is the coordinate algebra of a cuspidal cubic, while $B$ is the coordinate algebra of a nodal cubic, so they are not isomorphic. Neither $A$ nor $B$ are integrally closed, since $t^3/t^2\in Frac(A)$ and $(t^3-t)/(t^2-1)\in Frac(B)$ both square to $t^2$ but $t$ is not in $A$ nor $B$, so neither $A$ nor $B$ can be $\Bbb C[t]$, which is integrally closed.
